# how to assign nodejs ip address with port to domainname?

Tags: node.js, subdomain

I have developed an application previously in php and now I made in nodejs and there are 15 domains and with all domains, there are 1 sub-domain.

I don't know how to access my node application by domain name. Right now I access my application by ip.

Following are some of domain example which I earlier setup in php.

> Domains

```
www.abc.com
www.abc.de
www.abc.uk
www.abc.nl
staging.abc.com
```

Now I don't know how to setup domains for nodejs application? Guide me about this issue.